# Back Navigation does not restore the last fragment

Tags: android, android-fragments, navigationbar, fragment-backstack

I have a problem with `back navigation` since it does not restore the last fragment. All activities are `AppCompatActivity` using navigation_drawer(`ActivityA`) and scroll_activity(`ActivityB`) template of Android Studio

- `ActivityA` shows `fragment_1` (OK)
- Replace `fragment_1` with `fragment_2` (OK)
- Start `ActivityB` by clicking a button in `fragment_2` (OK)

  - If I click system' back button, I can see `ActivityB` (**GOOD**)
  - If I click the `back` navigation of `ActivityB`, then it display `fragment_1` rather than  `fragment_2`**(NOT GOOD)**

What I have tried are:

1. Create a static variable to control which fragment is shown, and try to render again at `onResume()` but it doesnot work.
2. Followed this [link](http://developer.android.com/training/implementing-navigation/temporal.html#SynthesizeBackStack) but not work also.

Any help? Thanks

Comment: Have you tried `setRetainInstance(true)` in fragment_2?

Comment: Where to use this? I place that in `onCreateView` and it has no effect.

Comment: If you customize the back navigation while using fragment use this line  in OnBackpressed in Activity .Fragment currentfragment=getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.view);which gives current visible fragment instance...
        if(currentfragment instanceof yourFragment){ //your code }

Comment: @NguyenDoanTung: in `onCreateView` of `fragment_2` add `setRetainInstance(true)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I forget one simple solution is [Activity Launch Mode](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/activity-element.html#lmode). I modified activity in the Manifest file like this and everything works normally.

```
 <activity
            android:name=".ActivityA"
            android:launchMode="singleTask"
            android:label="@string/app_name"
            android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar">
```

The problem is the `back navigation` button tried to create the `ActivityA` again (maybe it is because of scroll activity template behaviour).

Answer (score 1):

Hi Nguyen i created the same scene but getting fragment_2 on top after back from activityB

This my code
`public class FirstActivity extends ActionBarActivity {

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_first);
    if (savedInstanceState == null) {
        getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction().add(R.id.container, new PlaceholderFragment1()).commit();
    }
}

/**
 * A placeholder fragment containing a simple view.
 */
public static class PlaceholderFragment1 extends Fragment {

    public PlaceholderFragment1() {
    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_first, container, false);
        Button button = (Button) rootView.findViewById(R.id.btn);
        button.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                getActivity().getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction().add(R.id.container, new PlaceholderFragment2()).commit();
            }
        });
        return rootView;
    }
}

public static class PlaceholderFragment2 extends Fragment {

    public PlaceholderFragment2() {
    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_second, container, false);
        Button button = (Button) rootView.findViewById(R.id.btn);
        button.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Intent intent = new Intent(getActivity(), Secondctivity.class);
                startActivity(intent);
            }
        });
        return rootView;
    }
}
```

}
`

This my Manifest File

```
<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
    <activity
        android:name=".FirstActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>

    <activity
        android:name=".Secondctivity"
        android:label="@string/title_activity_secondctivity" >
    </activity>
</application>
```

Comment: I may try this, but `ActionBarActivity` is deprecated. Currently, I use `AppCompatActivity` and Android Studio provided templates.